# Which two matrices will create the zero matrix multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I was thinking, which property of matrices could help me determine if the multiplication of some $A$ and $B$ result the zero matrix?

Comment: Nilpotence? Tends to be for triangular matrices, but that is not a requirement.

Comment: @GitGud sorry removing it

Comment: I always get this stuff named wrong but it's something like the null space of A has to equal the (column space?) of B, or...something.

Comment: 0 determinant is necessary but not sufficient.

Comment: @DanUznanski why not sufficient? It is the only thing to ask if the matrix is square! And a matrix with some elements of the null space as columns gives you the answer!

Comment: @DanUznanski I think you mean the column space of $B$ is contained in the null space of $A$.

Comment: Those sound right.  And "not sufficient" because a determinant of 0 means merely that there is *some* nullspace, not that *everything* is the nullspace, which is what the 0 matrix says.

Comment: ${\cal R} B \subset \ker A$ **iff** $AB=0$.

Comment: It is just the Row Space? (not the column space?)

Comment: Orthogonality...

Answer (score 1):

Hint : Let $T$ and $S$ be two linear transformation from $ V \rightarrow V$ with matrices $M_1$ and $M_2$. What will happen to $S \circ T$ if range of $T$ is contained in the Kernal of $S$ ?

Comment: Can any body tell me, how to type function composition symbol in latex?

Comment: $\circ$ (\circ) should do.

Comment: @kban thanks. it works.

Comment: @GA316 is it another way of "saying" row space contained in the Null space?

Comment: @gbox I am completely agreeing with you, but if you say range is contained in kernal, it saying clear that composition is zero. But for the beginners it is not obvious that row space contained in the null space implying that the composition is zero. I believe so.